# When Reordering Magento gives me a blank screen

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, reorder

Recently I've tarred and dumped my Magento store on production (PHP 5.3, Mysql 5.1, Apache 2.2) and imported it on my local environment (PHP 5.3, Mysql 5.5, Apache 2.2). I've turned on all the logging possible in magento and in the php.ini and I've upped my php memory_limit to 256M, my php max_execution_time is at 18000 and compilation is disabled in Magento. When I try to reorder something I get a blank screen and nothing appears in my logs (Magento or apache2), so far this only happens when I try to reorder something. When I disable all my shopping cart rules it works fine. Any advice would be of great help !

Comment: Please be more specific about "blank screen". At what point does this happen? When adding a product to the cart? When submitting the order?

Comment: First: if you are using Enterprise you should be able to get help through Enterprise support. Failing that, in which environment are you having this issue? Have you enabled developer mode?

Comment: Take a look at the url and find the corresponding controller.  Start `echo` developing your way through if you're really stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Pro tip:** disable any and all extra modules installed that are not native to Magento. If that solves the problem, then re-enable each module one by one until you find the one that is causing the problem.

If you can't find the problem using that method, then disable your theme and see if the problem occurs again while using the base theme.